How to set the location of an object relative to the Form
I need that when I click on the button, the contextMenuStrip appears under it.
If you do this, the ContextMenuStrip appears outside the form, in the corner of the screen.
contextMenuStripButton1.Show(new Point(labelDataBase.Location.X, labelDataBase.Location.Y +      labelDataBase.Height));


In case it helps: this will show the context menu where the cursor is: contextMenuStripButton1.Show(Cursor.Position);.

Read the notes here: How to position a Popup Menu to the left side of a Button? (then get the code :)
